# Newton Method for Scalar Field

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson

I understand how Newton Method comes naturally from linear Taylor approximation of the function.

For $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
x_{new}=x+\Delta x
\\
f(x+\Delta x)=f(x)+f'(x)\Delta x=0
\\
f'(x)\Delta x=-f(x)
\\
\Delta x=-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}
\\
x_{new}=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}
$$

For vector field $\textbf{F}: \mathbb{R^{n}}\to \mathbb{R^{n}} $ we have
$$
\textbf{x}_{new}=\textbf{x}+\Delta \textbf{x}
\\
\textbf{F}(\textbf{x}+\Delta \textbf{x})=\textbf{F}(\textbf{x})+\textbf{J}(\textbf{x})\Delta\textbf{x}=0
\\
\textbf{J}(\textbf{x})\Delta\textbf{x}=-\textbf{F}(\textbf{x})
\\
\Delta\textbf{x}=-\textbf{J}(\textbf{x})^{-1}\textbf{F}(\textbf{x})
\\
\textbf{x}_{new}=\textbf{x}-\textbf{J}(\textbf{x})^{-1}\textbf{F}(\textbf{x})
$$

I'm working with scalar field, but I can't figure out Newton Method for it.

For scalar field $f: \mathbb{R^{n}}\to \mathbb{R}$
$$
\textbf{x}_{new}=\textbf{x}+\Delta \textbf{x}
\\
f(\textbf{x}+\Delta \textbf{x})=f(\textbf{x})+\nabla f(\textbf{x})\cdot \Delta\textbf{x}=0
\\
\nabla f(\textbf{x})\cdot \Delta\textbf{x}=-f(\textbf{x})
\\
?
$$

Dot product or non-square matrices doesn't have reciprocal inverse. Am I right that we don't have Newton Method for scalar fields because the derivation of it through Taylor approximation leads to this underdetermined equation $\nabla f(\textbf{x})\cdot \Delta\textbf{x}=-f(\textbf{x})$, which have infinitely many solutions? Can we still somehow use Newton Method or something alike for this kind of problems?

Comment: What is usually meant is the Newton method for optimization, that is, finding the roots of the gradient field with the second variant above.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I believe whenever Newton Method means Newton Method for optimization or Newton Method for root-finding is completely context specific. Since Newton Method for optimization is an extension of Newton Method for root-finding I would say Newton Method for root-finding is what is meant if no context is given.

Comment: It gets sometimes conflated, but more often in the other direction, some people wonder that there are Newton methods that do not use the Hessean matrix of second derivatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you correctly identified, when you have a scalar field the system
$$
f(x) + \nabla f(x) \cdot \Delta x = 0
$$
has an infinite number of solutions. One approach is to choose the "nearest" solution, in the sense that
$$
x_{\text{new}} = \arg\min_{y} \left\{\|y - x\|^2 \mid f(x) + \nabla f(x) \cdot (y - x) = 0 \right\}.
$$
The program above yields a closed-form update, given by
$$
x_{\text{new}} = x - \frac{f(x)}{\|\nabla f(x)\|^2} \cdot \nabla f(x).
\qquad (\dagger)
$$
The update $(\dagger)$ is sometimes known in the literature as the *Polyak step size*.

Comment: thank you! So basically we can say that even though in Newton Method for root-finding of scalar field we get underdetermined equation, the best we can do is actually moving along the gradient. i.e. $\Delta \textbf{x}=\lambda\nabla f(\textbf{x})$ where $\lambda$ is some scalar. Thus our Taylor expansion becomes $f(\textbf{x})+\nabla f(\textbf{x})\cdot \Delta\textbf{x}=f(\textbf{x})+\nabla f(\textbf{x})\cdot \lambda\nabla f(\textbf{x})=f(\textbf{x})+\lambda \left\| \nabla f(\textbf{x}) \right\|^{2}=0$

Comment: ... and from there we can easily find our scalar $\lambda=-\frac{f(\textbf{x})}{\left\| \nabla f(\textbf{x}) \right\|^{2}}$ and thus $\Delta\textbf{x}=\lambda \nabla f(\textbf{x}) = -\frac{f(\textbf{x})}{\left\| \nabla f(\textbf{x}) \right\|^{2}} \nabla f(\textbf{x})$

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider the more general problem of solving $$g(x) = 0$$ where $g : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and there are more unknowns than equations, i.e., $m \leq n$. The Jacobian $Dg(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ of $g$ at the point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the $m$ by $n$ matrix of first order partial derivatives. We shall write $\text{Ker} A$ and $\text{Ran}(A)$ to denote the kernel (aka null space) and the range (aka column space) of the matrix $A$.

Now let us derive Newton's method from scratch. If $g$ is differentiable at $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then by definition, we have
$$
g(x + \Delta x) = g(x) + Dg(x) \Delta x + o(\|\Delta x \|), \quad \Delta x \rightarrow 0, \quad x \not = 0.
$$
We therefore seek to solve the central linear equation
$$ 
0 = g(x) + Dg(x) y
$$
with respect to $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. If $n > m$, then there is potentially infinitely many solution of this equation. In particular, if $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ solves the central equation and $z \in \text{Ker}~Dg(x)$, then $y + z$ is also a solution, because
$$
0 = g(x) + Dg(x) y = g(x) + Dg(x)(y + z).
$$
Conversely, if $y_1$ and $y_2$ both solve the central equation , then  $y_1 - y_2 \in \text{Ker}~Dg(x)$. Now, if $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is *any* vector, then there exist exactly one vector
$$
u \in \text{Ker}~Dg(x)
$$
and exactly one vector
$$
v \in \left( \text{Ker}~Dg(x) \right) ^\perp = \text{Ran}~Dg(x)^T
$$
such that
$$
y = u + v.
$$
For this reason, we limit our search for a solution of the central equation to vectors $y \in \text{Ran}~Dg(x)^T$. Now let $y \in \text{Ran}~Dg(x)^T$, then there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that
$$
y = Dg(x)^T \lambda.
$$
We see that $y$ solves the central equation if and only if
$$
0 = g(x) + Dg(x) Dg(x)^T \lambda.
$$
This is the reason why Newton's method takes the form
$$
x_{k+1} = x_k - Dg(x_k)^T s_k
$$
where $s_k \in \mathbb{R}^m$ solves the linear system
$$
Dg(x_k) Dg(x_k)^T s_k = g(x_k).
$$
The central matrix
$$
A_k =  Dg(x_k) Dg(x_k)^T \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}
$$
is nonsingular, *precisely* when Jacobian $Dg(x_k)$ has full rank $m$.

---

In OP's case $m=1$ and the Jacobian has full rank when the gradient is not the zero vector.